# How to fetch user healthkit data from browser Application

Tags: ios, node.js, iphone, web, healthkit

Hi I'm trying to create an web Application that can directly get iOS users health data from healthkit apis I hade the following questions

1. Is it possible to do so without creating a mobile Application and using web Application only.
2. How do I get authorization from user to use his healthkit data.
3. If have permissions from user How can I directly hit healthkit api from my service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to access HealthKit using web APIS. You can only do so using native iOS APIs.